# Gradle failed to build because of google play services

Tags: android

My gradle builds fine until I add admob in my gradle:

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

I get an error while building:

```
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.
```

here is my versions:

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
```

Comment: have you downloaded latest play services from sdk manager?

Answer (score 0):

Bean, Follow this website https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

here they have listed the number of play services gradle dependencies with their latest versions. so use the two of them you required and you will be fine to go ahead.

Mr Bean, I think try Invalidate cache and restart and the rebuild the project with latest dependencies of Google services and try.

Comment: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi is referenced as an interface from com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj.

Answer (score 0):

You have analytics 9.0 and ads 17.1.1. Maybe issue is in that?

Comment: please check my commend under the 2nd answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message : Use Play services version `11.4.2`

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'

Otherwise probably you're using an old `builde.gradle` file with a `'google-services:3.2.0'`,

You should delete the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Because `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` already has same package.

That's where the conflict arises.

Comment: Im confused. would appreciate if we continue this discussion in a chat

Comment: Hey bro, did u change the version ? otherwise can u share with us your gradle file.